# libbullet not installed

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm attempting to do a manual install of a lower version of gazebo for a specific work environment.

Since I was working on a blank Ubuntu OS that never had gazebo installed. I first used sudo apt-get install gazebo,then sudo apt-get remove gazebo to keep the dependencies, but not the up-to-date version.

However, when I try to install the package I want, it goes like this:

sudo dpkg -i gazebo_1.7.3-1~precise_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package gazebo.
(Reading database ... 188459 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking gazebo (from gazebo_1.7.3-1~precise_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gazebo:
gazebo depends on libbullet; however:
Package libbullet is not installed.
dpkg: error processing gazebo (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
gazebo

Apparently, there is still one dependency that wasn't added. How do I go about installing libbullet?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4472/libbullet-not-installed/) by [David Jeang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/349/david-jeang/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 34 on 2013-09-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Jeang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/349/david-jeang/) on 2013-09-30**:
Just to clarify. sudo apt-get install libbullet-dev did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Looks like a problem with the libbullet version needed by gazebo.

While ubuntu ships 2.80, gazebo uses 2.81, so you will need to install debs from the OSRF repository. Two ways:

- Download libbullet-dev and libbullet-2.81 manually from [OSRF package repository](http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bullet/).
- Easier: [add the OSRF repository](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.9/install) to your system and install libbullet-dev from there.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2013-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Jeang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/349/david-jeang/) on 2013-09-30**:
ran sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu precise main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-latest.list'    then wget [http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bullet/libbullet-dev_2.81-2ppa1~precise_amd64.deb](http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bullet/libbullet-dev_2.81-2ppa1%7Eprecise_amd64.deb)  and wget [http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bullet/libbullet_2.81-2ppa1~precise_amd64.deb](http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bullet/libbullet_2.81-2ppa1%7Eprecise_amd64.deb)      then sudo dpkg -i for both     that seemed to do the trick.

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2013-10-02**:
Right, but you have mixed the methods. Only with download and dpkg -i should be enough, you don't need to setup the repository if you are not going to use apt-get install to get the packages.